# Authorizing sections of a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, forms-authentication

I was wondering if it's possible to authorize parts of a view inside the view.

For example, I understand how to authorize the entire controller in this method

```
<HandleError()> _
Public Class HomeController
  Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  Function Index()
    Return View()
  End Function

  <Authorize(Roles:="Administrators")> _
  Function AdministratorSecrets()
    Return View()
  End Function

End Class
```

But what Id like to do is have it so if the admin is logged in, they can see additional links in my navigation.

Something along the lines of

```
            <ul id="menu">              
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                <Authorize(Roles:="Administrators")> _
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Home")%></li>
            </ul>
```

Obviously that won't work, but it gives an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<% if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")){ %>
<span>HTML Code</span>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You may want to think about long term maintainability with this approach.  I would rather see the Model for the view have a flag CanSeeAdminSecrets and set that flag from the controller using the Roles.IsUserInRole method.  

The definition of an Admin could change in the system at a later point and having the logic for what an admin is in the controller makes more sense. Thought it's just preference really.

Comment: If you are going to go through that, it would be better to place such code in an extention method of the Roles class--adding it to the model just moves the definition from a number of views to about the same number of controller actions--if it were in an extension method the definition would be in one spot.

Comment: Here is a fairly full example I wrote. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54118/asp-net-mvc-features-based-authorization. You would have to author your own database tables based on the concept but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's the best practice to send the if stuff to the new html helper extension method.

Comment: Please add some references to where this information was taken.